# How to manage a set of Akka futures

Tags: scala, functional-programming, future

I have a Set of Future[T] that I want to manage into a single object for a library I am writing. In my current implementation I'm using a Future.sequence to collect them all and wait until they've resolved so I can do futurey things on them (map, collect, filter).  However this only gives me the ability to match on Success or Failure, which is not necessarily the case for the collection of futures I'm dealing with. Some will fail and some will succeed and I would like to be able to extract the values I can from those that succeed and collect the exceptions and errors on the others so that I can escalate them appropriately. In pseudo code it would be something like

```
Future.sequence(Set[Future[T]]) andThen {
  case FullSuccess => "woot"
  case SomeErrors  => "well, that's still ok."
  case FullErrors  => "Ok, who's the wise guy."
}
```

What I'm really looking for is to have data where there is data and not have to return a complete failure if only 1 of the futures in the sequence has failed.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no builtin helper for your case, but it's easy to create your own:

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt

def sequenceOfTries[T](futures: Seq[Future[T]]): Future[Seq[Try[T]]] =
  futures.foldLeft(Future.successful(List[Try[T]]())) {
    case (accF, f) => accF.flatMap {
      acc => f.map(v => Success(v) :: acc).recover { case ex => Failure(ex) :: acc }
    }
  }.map(_.reverse)


val v = Seq(
  Future.successful(1),
  Future.failed(new IllegalStateException("2")),
  Future.successful(3),
  Future.failed(new IllegalStateException("4"))
)

Await.result(sequenceOfTries(v), 1.second)
```

Results:

```
v: Seq[scala.concurrent.Future[Int]] = List(scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise@2416f7e5, scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise@2aaf675d, scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise@360d48f, scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise@230f8be2)    

res0: Seq[scala.util.Try[Int]] = List(Success(1), Failure(java.lang.IllegalStateException: 2), Success(3), Failure(java.lang.IllegalStateException: 4))
```

**UPD**. Alternatively you can utilize `Future.sequence` like this (with same result):

```
def sequenceOfTries[T](futures: Seq[Future[T]]): Future[Seq[Try[T]]] =
  Future.sequence(futures.map(_.map(x => Success(x)).recover { case ex => Failure(ex) }))
```

Comment: Turning a `Future[T]` that might be failed into a `Future[Try[T]]` that is guaranteed to be successful is common enough to warrant its own helper method, imho.